# Need to Selectively Merge Records to Different Places in a Word Directory-type Document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge, field-codes

My company regularly creates "rosters" (or directory documents) that list contact info for people with roles for a trust fund. The rosters have a certain format -- people with an "Administrator" role are listed at the top, then people with the Attorney role, etc., then below a line are two columns--the left is for records with Union Trustee roles, the right is for records with Management Trustee roles.

If the list of contacts is an Excel document and Role is one of the fields, (or columns), is it possible to merge the contacts records to certain places in the Word document based on their value in the Role field? I can make sure the Excel document is sorted by Role in the order the contacts will need to be inserted, and make sure the Word document allows inserted the maximum number of possible records for each section, but I don't know how to make Word jump to a new section if the next record has a certain Role value.

Thank you!!

Comment: I've rethought a solution -- can you tell me if this is possible?:

If the records in Excel are merged in the same "Role" as needs to be inserted in the Word document, can a marker in the Excel document tell Word when to jump to the next section?

In other words, can Word look for a value in a certain field and only merge the records with that value in a different section?